# how to choose hardware while building performance oriented linux server to run different application?

Tags: linux, hadoop, server, architecture, cpu

how to select which disk, CPU and RAM to choose while building performance oriented linux server to run application like kafka, spark, hadoop.
What hardware can be selected and what can be the reason to choose particular hardware

Comment: The question is pretty generic and it is difficult to give a clear answer. Even when running a big data/streaming analytics stack, the cluster dimensioning rules may vary from application to application. For example, you may need a swarm of smaller-capacity machines or a reduced number of large capacity ones depending on your scalability requirements, you may need SSDs for disk-intensive applications etc. Just google for "spark cluster dimensioning" or "big data cluster dimensioning" for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this [Link](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/deployment.html). This link contains the basic details about the server, disk, filesystem exact JVM options required to setup Kafka on production